# eval() triggers Unexpected number when part of string passed into it has decimal

Tags: javascript

The below works perfectly until a key is sent to it with a decimal in it. Then it triggers an "Unexpected number". I can think of some work arounds that have to do with modifying the keys in the object sent from the database, but want to figure out why this triggers an error first.

What is happening in the below:

1. A number of percentiles are sent from the FE by the user (e.g., 5th, 15th, 35th, 62.5th, etc.) as an object (e.g. `incP1: 5th, incP2: 15th, etc.`) which are then mapped.
2. If the key starts with `inc` it does a certain set of logic.
3. It constructs a string (`fieldStr`) that corresponds with a key in the `cr` object which is basically the actual values of the percentiles the user requested.
4. In this case it would construct something like `cr.TestInc15`
5. The `let fieldObj = eval(fieldStr)` then returns the value from `cr.` of the key that was constructed.

Hopefully that makes sense, but that is why I am using `eval()` because I can't get the value from just the key as string otherwise. It works fine until it hits something like the 62.5th percentile where the key would be constructed as `cr.TestInc62.5` which definitely has a value in `cr.` as I can `console.log` it out.

---

```
renderData(percentiles, cr, varName) {
    return (
        _.map(
            _.pickBy(percentiles, function (value, key) {
                return _.startsWith(key, 'inc')
            }), p => {
                let fieldStr = 'cr.' + varName + 'Inc' +
                    (p == 'n' ? 'N' :
                        (p == 50 ? 'Median' : p
                        ));

                // a bunch of junk after this, but error stops it here
                let fieldObj = eval(
                    fieldStr
                );
            }
        )
    )
}
```

Comment: You could avoid the `eval` and use the `[]` bracket notation to access the properties. Something like `fieldObj = cr[fieldStr]` where you would omit the `cr.` from the `fieldStr`

Comment: Could you try making a minimal example that demonstrates the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course you can get the value with a string, you can access an object property without using eval even in your case of having dots as part of property names.

It's called **bracket notation**

See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors

```js
var cr = { "TestInc62.5": "Val123" }

console.log(cr["TestInc62.5"]);
```